# Support multiple AuthenticationSchemes of same type

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Im workign with IdentityServer4 and trying to add multiple external providers of same type, OpenIdConnect in my case. However I'm running into some issues.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
// Azure AD
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Azure AD", x =>
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-client-id";
    x.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
})
// Identity Server
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "My Other Identity Server", x =>
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-other-client-id";
    x.Authority = "http://localhost:6000"; //Another Identity Server I want to treat as external provider
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };
});
```

Causes:

```
Scheme already exists: oidc
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String name, Action`1 configureBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddScheme>b__0(AuthenticationOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
```

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
// Azure AD
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Azure AD", x =>
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-client-id";
    x.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
})
// Identity Server
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-idserver", "My Other Identity Server", x =>
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-other-client-id";
    x.Authority = "http://localhost:6000"; //Another Identity Server I want to treat as external provider
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };
});
```

If I give them different schemes, then I get the following exception, when the external provider posts back.

Causes:

```
Exception: Correlation failed.
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Haven't tried this scenario yet so I'm not sure about this: Could you try adding a CallbackPath to both handlers? E.g. `/aad-callback` and `/idserver-callback`. You will need to configure the reply URLs on both providers a bit differently then.

Comment: I think junnas is right and the "Correlation failed" error is due to not having a different callback URL for each provider. 
In my case I needed it to be data driven based on config associated with a user's email domain so created my own middleware that could accept all the settings it needed value the properties passed to the Challenge method.

Comment: @eugene-s, in what part of your codebase do you have the logic to select one of the oidc authentication schemes ("oidc" or "oidc-idserver") ? Can you share what that code looks like ?

Comment: You would have to use ChallengeAsync and pass in the scheme. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2  . The way you would present that to the user is by rendering different button for each scheme and then raising ChallengeAsync.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As commenters suggested the solution is to add specific `CallbackPath` and `SignedOutCallbackPath` so that middleware can know which external provider is running.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
// Azure AD
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Azure AD", x =>    
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-client-id";
    x.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };

    // Callbacks for middleware to properly correlate
    x.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc-az");
    x.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc-az");
})
// Identity Server
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-idserver", "My Other Identity Server", x =>    
{
    x.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    x.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    x.ClientId = "some-other-client-id";
    x.Authority = "http://localhost:6000"; //Another Identity Server I want to treat as external provider
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };

    // Callbacks for middleware to properly correlate
    x.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc-so");
    x.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc-so");
});
```

Comment: hi, can you show or explain configuraiton of new endpoints (CallbackPath, SignedOutCallbackPath  ), new methods which call some bsae signin-oidc and signout-oidc ?

Comment: The specific `CallbackPath` and `SignedOutCallbackPath` you would configure in the target identity provider as allowed sites. So when the target identity provider posts back it would post back to route you have configured in `CallbackPath` and Oidc middleware will pick the correct configuration to use.